# Error creating logfile under a directory in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create the logfile under `log` directory in my ruby script but it is returning `org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (Errno::ENOENT) file:/home/ABC/tool/log/file_name.log`
 error. Below is the piece the code where I am trying to do the same.

```
FileUtils.mkdir 'log'
$LOG_PATH = "#{File.expand_path("../../../log",__FILE__)}"
File.new("#{$LOG_PATH}/file_name.log")
file = File.open('file_name.log', File::APPEND)
logger = Logger.new(file, 'daily')
```

The above code is creating the `log` folder but it is not creating the `file_name.log` and giving `Errno::ENOENT` error.

Can someone guide me creating `file_name.log` under `log` folder?

Also I tried to the run the code copied below to see if it is able to create the log file under current directory and it is working fine.

```
$LOG = Logger.new('file_name.log', 'daily')
```

Comment: Using global variables, *especially* those in all-caps, is probably a super bad idea. Is there anything wrong with using a regular constant like `LOG_PATH`? There's also no reason to define this as a string like `"#{...}"` when `File.expand_path(...)` alone should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked.

```
FileUtils.mkdir 'log'
$LOG_PATH = "#{File.expand_path("../../../log",__FILE__)}"
Dir.chdir "#{$LOG_PATH}"
$LOG = Logger.new('file_name.log', 'daily')
```

Comment: `logger = Logger.new(File.expand_path("../../../log/file_name.log",__FILE__), 'daily')` is enough, no need to chdir. You were trying to pass in an open file handle before and I guess that doesn't work. Logger takes filename as argument.

Comment: @Kimmo - Thank you. Will try that.